# Issues with trying to create a generic data type with classes C++

Tags: c++

I am having an issue with my C++ program. Right now I am just trying to create a generic "variable" utilizing operator overloading. So the issues is when I determine 
the type of data passed. (I must do this because I am later overloading the << operator so that ostream can output the correct data) The conditional statement 
does not work as expected. Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>

class SLVar
{
    public:
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const SLVar& var);
        const char* str;
        char ch;
        int in;
        float fl;
        double dl;
        const char* type; //Later initialized
        template <typename T>
        T operator=(T var)
        {
            if (typeid(T).name() == typeid(int).name())
            {
                type = "int"; in = var;
            }
            else if (typeid(T).name() == typeid(const char*).name())
            {
                type = "string"; str = var;
            }
            else if (typeid(T).name() == typeid(float).name())
            {
                type = "float"; fl = var;
            }
            else if (typeid(T).name() == typeid(double).name())
            {
                type = "double"; fl = var;
            }
            else if (typeid(T).name() == typeid(char).name())
            {
                type = "char"; ch = var;
            }
        }
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, SLVar& var)
{
    if (var.type == "string")
    {
        os << var.str;
    }
    else if (var.type == "int")
    {
        os << var.in;
    }
    else if (var.type == "float")
    {
        os << var.fl;
    }
    else if (var.type == "double")
    {
        os << var.dl
    }
    else if (var.type == "char")
    {
        os << var.ch;
    }
    return os;
}
int main()
{
    SLVar var;
    var = 5;
    std::cout << var << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

That should be the final code once that class is done. But the error persists when I try to set var = blah. It gives cannot convert const char* to int or 
cannot convert char to int or anything of the sort. It was my impression that that code does not matter at all if it is not true. If I comment out the part 
where I set the correct variables it runs with no issue

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>

class SLVar
{
    public:
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const SLVar& var);
        const char* str;
        char ch;
        int in;
        float fl;
        double dl;
        const char* type; //Later initialized
        template <typename T>
        T operator=(T var)
        {
            if (typeid(T).name() == typeid(int).name())
            {
                type = "int"; //in = var;
            }
            else if (typeid(T).name() == typeid(const char*).name())
            {
                type = "string"; //str = var;
            }
            else if (typeid(T).name() == typeid(float).name())
            {
                type = "float"; //fl = var;
            }
            else if (typeid(T).name() == typeid(double).name())
            {
                type = "double"; //fl = var;
            }
            else if (typeid(T).name() == typeid(char).name())
            {
                type = "char"; //ch = var;
            }
        }
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, SLVar& var)
{
    if (var.type == "string")
    {
        os << var.str;
    }
    else if (var.type == "int")
    {
        os << var.in;
    }
    else if (var.type == "float")
    {
        os << var.fl;
    }
    else if (var.type == "double")
    {
        os << var.dl;
    }
    else if (var.type == "char")
    {
        os << var.ch;
    }
    return os;
}
int main()
{
    SLVar var;
    var = "Hello world";
    std::cout << var << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This runs, but only when I comment var = blah as shown above. So how can I fix this? Again it was my understanding that if the if statement is not true 
the code inside wont even run. But it seem to anyway. I do not understand why this is happening. Can someone shed some light on it? Basically all I want to 
do is create a "generic data type" and use the operator=() to set it.

Comment: shouldn't you return something from `T operator=(T var)` ? and shouldn't the prototype be `T & operator=(const T &var)` ? and for `<<` the prototype should be `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const SLVar& var)`

Comment: Could you post it as an answer?

Comment: not sure how you want to use that type, but I am quite sure that there is an easier way to achieve the same

Comment: There are better approaches than endless `if-else-if` blocks. Look into how other libraries implement the `variant` type.

Comment: We are limit on server space. We cannot download 3rd party libs. This is a CGI Script I am working on.

Comment: why dont you make the whole class a template with a single member of type `T`?

Comment: @tobi303 could you possibly write an example as an answer?

Comment: @AlexWalker: I cannot post as answer because it fixes _some_ problems. If I answered I would drop the type check because it cannot work that way. Either write 1 method per type or do as tobi303 says.

Comment: Do you really need two instances holding values of different types to be of the same type? I cannot give you a good example without knowing the requirements

Comment: I just want to make a generic variable and overload the operator<< to be able to print it.

Comment: operator=() is required to set it for now

Comment: ok let me ask differently, do you need the same instance to hold values of different types, or only seperate instances holding values of different types? Actually it is not clear what you want to achieve, because `ostream` already is able to print `int`,`float`, etc. generically

Comment: [`.name()` is implementation defined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info) and not required to be non-empty let alone unique; rather than comparing `name()`s, you could just use `typeinfo::operator==` directly, as in `if (typeid(T) == typeid(int))`, but it's even better to use [`std::is_same<T, int>::value`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same).

Comment: BTW: `if (var.type == "string")` is bound to fail with `type` being `const char *` (just for your future programs :))

Comment: This would be a good application for SFINAE  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre type is like a label. "int" for int "char" for char and "string" for const char* its just a label you could say. An ID persay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the need is to be able to declare:

```
SLVar var;
```

and later decide to assign integer, string, float, whatever without the need of fixing the type by a template (kind of dynamic typing)

I'm proposing a solution with a lot of compromises, without typeinfo at all and without templates (the template is useless here since you have to perform a type check within the function)

either, I kept only `const char *` and `int` types for simplicity's sake but that can be easily extended.

When assigning, the type is set in an enumerate, later used by the console write function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>

class SLVar
{
    private:
        const char* str;
        int in;
        enum TheType { TYPE_INT, TYPE_CHARPTR, TYPE_UNKNOWN };
        TheType type;

    public:
        SLVar() : type(TYPE_UNKNOWN)
        {}

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const SLVar& var);

        SLVar & operator=(int var)
        {
            in = var;
            type=TYPE_INT;
            return *this;
        }
        SLVar &operator=(const char *var)
        {
            str = var;
            type=TYPE_CHARPTR;
            return *this;
        }

};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const SLVar& var)
{
    switch (var.type)
    {
    case SLVar::TYPE_CHARPTR:
        return os << var.str;            
    case SLVar::TYPE_INT:
        return os << var.in;           
    default:
      return os;  // not printing anything
      }       
}
int main()
{
    SLVar var;
    var = "Hello world";
    std::cout << var << std::endl;    
    var = 35;    // kind of dynamic typing through assignment
    SLVar var2;
    var2 = 56;
    std::cout << var << " " << var2 << std::endl;

}
```

result:

```
Hello world
35 56
```

It's still missing a lot of things, like default constructor, copy constructor... but the principle works.

Comment: nitpicks accepted & fixed :) the `return os` part was lost in some copy/paste, and maybe the `main` method is too simplistic.

Comment: Thank you, this works very well. I thought by using a template it would be better than overloaded functions, but it works perfectly. Accepted answer and I will edit my question with the fixes a bit later.

Comment: Looks good.  Main word of caution: the stored `const char*`s will only be valid as long as the text they were pointed at remains there in memory.  It's much safer and common (albeit sometimes slower, and you won't "see" changes to the original text buffer when outputing the `SLVar`), to have a `std::string str;` member.  Separately, `boost::variant<>` provides a fully-fledged implementation of this kind of discriminated union, for anyone wanting to use this in anger and not as a learning exercise.

Comment: @TonyD I usually use std::string but eventually we are removing all libs support. Except for our own of course.

Comment: @TonyD: yes `std::string` is better (or a custom implementation). Didn't know about `boost::variant<>`. Must be less lame than my attempt :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>

template <typename T>
class SLVar {
public:
    SLVar<T>() {} ; // Defualt constructor
    SLVar<T>(T value) :
        var(value)
    {} ;

    T var ;
    T getvalue() {return var ;}

    // This lets you use the class as though it was the object
    inline operator T() {return var;}
    T operator=(T newvar)
    {
        var = newvar ;
    }
};

int main()
{
    SLVar<double> var_dbl(3.14);
    SLVar<int> var_int(5) ;
    SLVar<const char*> var_str("hello") ;
    SLVar<char> var_char('y') ;

    // And now to test...
    std::cout << "Dbl: " << var_dbl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Int: " << var_int << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Str: " << var_str << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Char: " << var_char << std::endl;

    // Lets try resetting the values
    var_dbl = 4.6 ;
    var_int = 7 ;
    var_str = "goodbye" ;
    var_char = 'n' ;

    std::cout << "Dbl: " << var_dbl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Int: " << var_int << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Str: " << var_str << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Char: " << var_char << std::endl;

    // Lets try some math on the double variable
    std::cout << "Dbl * 0.5: " << var_dbl*0.5 << " (this shoudl be 2.3)" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The downside is that (I'm I'm sure you've realized) the streamer wont work if you try to do `SLVar<std::string>`. There you just need to use `SLVar<const char*>`. I've also added the line:

```
inline operator T() {return var;}
```

So that the the class can act as an object of the type it is suppose to represent. So you can use the `SLVar<double>` as a double in a formula, for example.

Comment: This misses the point, which is to have one static type able to store values of several types, so that you could - for example - have a `vector<SLVar>` storing heteogenous data values, or a function able to return an `SLVar`, working around the inability to directly return the different types directly.  If you have `SLVar<>` as suggested, you might as well use the `double`, `int` etc types directly.

Comment: @ Tony D - I realize that now after re-reading the question. If you think it necessary I'll retract my answer.